# QT Creator - Parsing through CSV file

Tags: c++

OK, so I am using QT Creator for C++ and I am making a function that allows me to parse through the CSV file that I have named getExcelFile. Everything else is working fine but my code will not enter my while loop for some reason which is driving me crazy. Some suggestions would be helpful! Thanks.

```
void Widget::getExcelFile(){
    //Name of the Qfile object.
    //filename is the directory of the file once it has been selected in prompt
    QFile thefile(filename);
    //If the file isn't successfully open
    if (thefile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        qDebug() << "File opened successfully";
        //Converts text file to stream
        QTextStream in(&thefile);
        fileContent=in.readAll();
        QString line;
        while (!in.atEnd()){
            //line = textStream.readLine();//reads line from file
            //Will not enter this loop for some odd reason.
            qDebug() << "This text does not print out";
        }
    }

    qDebug() << "This prints out successfully";
    ui->textEdit->setPlainText(fileContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did `in.readAll()`, after that call `in.atEnd()` will return `true`. Either remove `in.readlAll()` or `while` loop, why do you need both?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I removed the in.readAll() line and it now enters the while loop. For some reason now, the loop is inside of an infinite loop. I only have 91 lines in the csv. But I believe I just have to iterate through the lines of the csv file and split them based on commas. I plan on storing the contents of each line into a structure. Do you have any suggestions for an approach for me. Thanks!

Comment: @MohamedDoumbouya I assume you uncommented `line = in.readLine();` inside the loop? Otherwise your stream will never reach the end. If you need to split the `QString`, then `QString::split()` should help you.